# Advanced Shapes and Determing Vertices

Tags: opengl, import, assets

I am learning OpenGL and am curious about how people craft some advanced shapes. Take for example a person model. If someone draws a person in OpenGL do they really have to sit down, plot the vertices and then construct triangles all by hand to make the person? I can't imagine people using OpenGL to make video games sitting and plotting vertices for every single 3D model? Do you really have to do this? Is there a more automated way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is - Maya, Max, and other 3D modeling programs do A LOT of this work for you.  These types of programs are how the advanced stuff is made.  It gives you large building blocks and tools well above the triangle level to speed things up, though you can access or add triangles if you want.

Comment: Try Blender.org for a free example

Comment: So is it a waste to learn about vertices in OpenGL?

Comment: Not at all - it's important to understand how the system works under the hood, and vertices are the basic building blocks of how the system works.  You need to learn your letters by writing them down even if you're going to do all your writing on a word processor :)

Comment: A good example of a case in which you need to specify vertices by code is automatic terrain generation, for instance if you want to create a pseudo-random land. Also, post-processing effects, explosions, particle effects, 2D impostors, usually require that you specify vertices by code and have a good understanding of the entire process. Actually even to draw your HUD on the screen you need to define the position of the various widgets (health, armor, ammo, crosshair...) using 2D vertices.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of a 3D application such as a video game, OpenGL is the interface between the 3D application itself and the graphic card driver; the commands that you issue to OpenGL are, in a way, *translated* and passed to the driver, which in turn is the interface between the software world and the graphic card. A complete 3D application usually needs a lot of other software components to be really interesting, and the most important for a game is certainly the **asset** system, which is used to *import* into your game all the **artistic** things, such as images, sound effects and 3D models (possibly including game levels). These artistic things, or assets, are made by artists using dedicated software packages. For 3D models, some of the most popular modeling applications are Blender, Maya, Max, Lightwave. Each one of these packages defines its own *document format*, which is used to save the asset to the disk; if you know the format, you can write a program that reads the file and issues the appropriate commands to OpenGL in order to render the scene. At the most basic level, you would need to find where in the file are the vertices stored, and use OpenGL to draw them. No engine that I am aware of really does this, that is, reading the content of the document of a modeling application, because they are extremely complex formats and in some case they are not even documented.

Instead, game engine developers usually create or buy or download for free a pair of programs:

- The **exporter** is a program that extract some relevant information from 3D document, and save it to a file; this can be a standalone program, or can be a plugin for the 3D application itself; as an example, Blender typically uses plugins written in Python, among which are exporter plugins.
- The **importer** is usually a library that you link to your game engine, and is able to load into memory the file exported by the exporter. Once you have this data structure load into memory, you can iterate over its fields and send the appropriate commands to OpenGL.

This is a very simple example with Blender; the following Python script is sufficient to export vertex positions. Usually you need to export also face (triangle) information in order to be able to export something interesting.

```
import bpy

object = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
mesh = object.to_mesh(scene = bpy.context.scene, apply_modifiers = True, settings = 'PREVIEW')

file = open('/Users/Damix/Cube.txt', 'w')

for v in mesh.vertices:
    file.write("%f %f %f\n" % (v.co[0], v.co[1], v.co[2]))

file.close()
```

For an actual cube, the above script outputs a file similar to this:

```
1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
-1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
-1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
1.000000 0.999999 1.000000
0.999999 -1.000001 1.000000
-1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
-1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
```

You can read this file into your game using something like this (for the C language):

```
float x, y, z;
FILE *file;

file = fopen("/Users/Damix/Cube.txt", "r");

while (fscanf(file, "%f %f %f", &x, &y, &z))
{
    glVertex3f(x, y, z);
}

fclose(file);
```

In modern OpenGL you would not use **glVertex3f** instead you would build an attribute buffer.

In real game engines you also need to export texture coordinates, normal information, material settings and the most frightening of all, animation data (if you have animation). 
Also, since the 3D modeling application could have different 3D conventions than OpenGL, you need to convert the data; for instance, despite the fact that Blender is written in OpenGL, it uses a reference frame in which the Z axis points upward.

It is usually wise to use a well known interchange format for which importers and exporters already exists for your 3D modeling package. Blender has out of the box support for exporting Alias Wavefront .OBJ, which is a very simple format for which it is not too difficult to write an importer. There are also other exporters but I'm not aware of their quality and I never really used them. You need to do your research and pick the right format for you.